# Wordpress configuring payment gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I put a credit card number into the mijireh gateway it has an error and says one or more parameters are missing. I have searched endlessly for a solution with no success.

I am not to sure if it is something in the code of the website or something, There are currently no errors on the site.

> Zamiafashion.com/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the error message exactly "One or more parameters are missing"?

Comment: Hang on ill check again sorry... :(

Comment: It actually says in it's entirety: Order failed: One or more parameters were missing or invalid

Comment: The API key for mijireh, the API's for pin (the people who take the money from mijireh) are all correct everything seems setup correctly.